# Printing and formatting a tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this:

```
record = (u'U9', [(u'U2', 1.0), (u'U10', 0.6666666666666666), (u'U2', 1.0)])
```

I want this as an printed output to a file:

```
U9:U2,U10
```

Note: Only unique values are needed in the output ( U2 is printed only once despite appearing twice)

I have tried using:

```
for i in record[1]:
   print record[1], ":", record[i[0]]
```

But this gives me:

```
U9:U2
U9:U10
U9:U2
```

Comment: By what rules are the values extracted from the list? Unique values only? In what order? I'm presuming that you only want to print `U2` once even though it appears twice. Please be *explicit* about what the rules are.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the unique values into a set, then join those into a single string:

```
unique = {t[0] for t in record[1]}
print '{}:{}'.format(record[0], ','.join(unique))
```

Demo:

```
>>> record = (u'U9', [(u'U2', 1.0), (u'U10', 0.6666666666666666), (u'U2', 1.0)])
>>> unique = {t[0] for t in record[1]}
>>> print '{}:{}'.format(record[0], ','.join(unique))
U9:U10,U2
```

Note that sets are unordered, which is why you get `U10,U2` for this input, and not `U2,U10`. See [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

If order matters, convert your list of key-value pairs to an [`collections.OrderedDict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), and get the keys from the result:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> unique = OrderedDict(record[1])
>>> print '{}:{}'.format(record[0], ','.join(unique))
U9:U2,U10
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Also, if I want them ordered (U2,U10) what can I add to the above?

Comment: @AmanMathur: you could use an `OrderedDict`; added that as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks you again. But strangely it does not order if the record = (u'U9', [(u'U10', 0.6666666666666666), (u'U2', 1.0)])
I am still getting U9:U10,U2

Comment: @AmanMathur: That's a *different order* from the input. Please be *explicit* about what order you want. You appear to want to *sort* the key, using a *natural order* (so only using the numbers). Use the set version, then sort that first using the answers from [Does Python have a built in function for string natural sort?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4836710)

Comment: Thank you. I however cannot use third party libraries for sorting.

Comment: @AmanMathur: please check **all** answers on that question. Only the accepted answer requires an external library.

Comment: data.sort(key=lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x).lower()) this one worked for me. Instead of tuple I had to use a list. Thank you. :)